# Bouncing ball/colour change animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to create a bouncing ball animation using jQuery and I want to change the colour after every bounce.

This is my animation but it's not working for some reason because I'm just a beginner.

```js
$("#btn3").click(function() {
  $("#bluecircle")
    .animate({
      left: "400px",
      bottom: "-60px",
      borderRadius: "50%",
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }, 850, "easeInSine")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "800px",
      borderRadius: "50%",
      marginTop: "50px"
    }, 850, "easeInOutSine")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "1200px",
      borderRadius: "50%",
      marginTop: "-50px"
    }, 850, "easeInOutSine")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "800px",
      borderRadius: "50%",
      marginTop: "50px"
    }, 850, "easeInOutSine")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "400px",
      borderRadius: "50%",
      marginTop: "-50px"
    }, 850, "easeInOutSine")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "0px",
      borderRadius: "50%",
      marginTop: "50px"
    }, 850, "easeInOutSine");
})
```

```css
#bluecircle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js" integrity="sha512-0QbL0ph8Tc8g5bLhfVzSqxe9GERORsKhIn1IrpxDAgUsbBGz/V7iSav2zzW325XGd1OMLdL4UiqRJj702IeqnQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="content" id="content3"> 
  <button id="btn3">Animate Blue Circle</button>
  <div id="bluecircle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and CSS in to the snippet I edited in to your question. Also note that jQuery (or JS in general) is not a good technology to use for complex animation as it performs so poorly. I'd strongly suggest you look in to using CSS for this

Comment: thank you for suggestion. can you help me out here because the color change after every bounce is not visible.

Comment: Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why is the ```border-radius``` in the animation? It doesn't change...

Comment: <div class="content" id="content3">
        <button id="btn3">Animate Blue Circle</button>
        <div id="bluecircle"></div>
    </div>

Comment: #bluecircle{
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: blue;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: relative;
        }

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under the question to add code to the question, as it's very hard to read in comments. I've done it for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** You added `border-radius` to the animation but it stays always `50%`. Therefor you can omit it in the animation. Furthermore, you are using bottom and left in the first animation and margin in the other animations. I suggest to use only one of both.

---

### **jQuery**

For animating the `background-color` you need `jQuery.ui`. For animating it only after every bounce you have to add the `background-color` to every second `animate()` (where `margin-top` decreases).

To have a bounce effect you have to add the easing only to `margin-top`.  The other properties should be animated with `linear`. Furthermore you need two different easings for the bouncing: `easeIn...` for increasing `margin-top` and `easeOut...` for decreasing. By the way `...Cubic` looks more natural as `...Sine`, for example `easeInCubic`.

**Working example:** For fitting in the stack snippet, i made it smaller and because it looks more natural i made it a bit faster.

I used for this example just left and bottom.

```js
$("#btn3").click(function() {

  $("#bluecircle")
    .animate({
      left: "150px",
      bottom: [ "-50px", "easeInCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      left: "300px",
      bottom: [ "50px", "easeOutCubic" ],
      backgroundColor: [ "red", "easeOutCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      left: "450px",
      bottom: [ "-50px", "easeInCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      left: "300px",
      bottom: [ "50px", "easeOutCubic" ],
      backgroundColor: [ "blue", "easeOutCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      left: "150px",
      bottom: [ "-50px", "easeInCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      left: "0px",
      bottom: [ "0px", "easeOutCubic" ],
      backgroundColor: [ "red", "easeOutCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear");
    
});
```

```css
#bluecircle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js" integrity="sha512-0QbL0ph8Tc8g5bLhfVzSqxe9GERORsKhIn1IrpxDAgUsbBGz/V7iSav2zzW325XGd1OMLdL4UiqRJj702IeqnQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="content" id="content3"> 
  <button id="btn3">Animate Blue Circle</button>
  <div id="bluecircle"></div>
</div>
```

But you can achieve exactly the same result with margin.

**Working example:**

```js
$("#btn3").click(function() {

  $("#bluecircle")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "150px",
      marginTop: [ "50px", "easeInCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "300px",
      marginTop: [ "-50px", "easeOutCubic" ],
      backgroundColor: [ "red", "easeOutCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "450px",
      marginTop: [ "50px", "easeInCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "300px",
      marginTop: [ "-50px", "easeOutCubic" ],
      backgroundColor: [ "blue", "easeOutCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "150px",
      marginTop: [ "50px", "easeInCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear")
    .animate({
      marginLeft: "0px",
      marginTop: [ "0px", "easeOutCubic" ],
      backgroundColor: [ "red", "easeOutCubic" ]
    }, 500, "linear");
    
});
```

```css
#bluecircle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js" integrity="sha512-0QbL0ph8Tc8g5bLhfVzSqxe9GERORsKhIn1IrpxDAgUsbBGz/V7iSav2zzW325XGd1OMLdL4UiqRJj702IeqnQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="content" id="content3"> 
  <button id="btn3">Animate Blue Circle</button>
  <div id="bluecircle"></div>
</div>
```

---

### **CSS keyframes**

Instead of jQuery `animate()` i suggest to use CSS `keyframe` animations for a specific class and just toggle that class on button click. The advantage is that you don't need any libraries and can have different percentages for the animated properties, so that for example the color change is more smooth.

**Working example:**
I used for this example just left and bottom. Notice the different percentages for the color.

```js
document.querySelector("#btn3").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector("#bluecircle").classList.add('animating');
});
```

```css
#bluecircle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.animating {
  animation: left 3s, bottom 3s, color 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes left {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  16.6% {
    left: 150px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  33.3% {
    left: 300px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  50% {
    left: 450px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  66.6% {
    left: 300px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  83.3% {
    left: 150px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
}

@keyframes bottom {
  0% {
    bottom: 0px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  16.6% {
    bottom: -50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
  }
  33.3% {
    bottom: 50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  50% {
    bottom: -50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
  }
  66.6% {
    bottom: 50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  83.3% {
    bottom: -50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  33.3% {
    background-color: red;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  66.6% {
    background-color: blue;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content3">
  <button id="btn3">Animate Blue Circle</button>
  <div id="bluecircle"></div>
</div>
```

---

But you can achieve exactly the same result with margin.

**Working example:**

```js
document.querySelector("#btn3").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector("#bluecircle").classList.add('animating');
});
```

```css
#bluecircle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.animating {
  animation: left 3s, top 3s, color 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes left {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  16.6% {
    margin-left: 150px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  33.3% {
    margin-left: 300px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 450px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  66.6% {
    margin-left: 300px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  83.3% {
    margin-left: 150px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
}

@keyframes top {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  16.6% {
    margin-top: 50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
  }
  33.3% {
    margin-top: -50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: 50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
  }
  66.6% {
    margin-top: -50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  83.3% {
    margin-top: 50px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0px;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  33.3% {
    background-color: red;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  66.6% {
    background-color: blue;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.550, .055, .675, .190);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content3">
  <button id="btn3">Animate Blue Circle</button>
  <div id="bluecircle"></div>
</div>
```